# Query on default SchemaRegistryClient used by KafkaAvroDeserializer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We are using a schema registry in our application and for deserialization, we use:

> KafkaAvroDeserializer kafkaAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();

We are currently using default constructor. However, I can see we have a few other options to override SchemaRegistryClient. In Confluent, I can see we have `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` present.

My questions are:

1. If we use default constructor, would KafkaAvroDeserializer invoke schema registry for each and every request on the topic, or would it cache the schema at the consumer?
2. For schema caching, do we need to explicitly use CachedSchemaRegistryClient to maintain a local cache?

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java

Answer (score 0):

[`new KafkaAvroDeserializer()` includes the CachedSchemaRegistry client](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java#L61-L75)

The other constructor is primarily for testing purposes.

> If we use default constructor, would KafkaAvroDeserializer invoke schema registry for each and every request on the topic, or would it cache the schema at the consumer

It caches

> For schema caching, do we need to explicitly use CachedSchemaRegistryClient to maintain a local cache?

As stated, the cache is internally managed for you

> We are currently using default constructor

Not really clear why you are doing that. `props.set("....deserializer", KafkaAvroDeserializer.class)` works fine in most cases